# SharePoint Online some options are greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, feature

I want to go to this document library and create a Flow to perform an automatic task.

Unofrotunatly, the options are greyed out and I dont know if it has to do something with premissions or just some Document Librarty Settings or the way the site was created.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a Flow you don't have to start in a particular document library. You can click the Office waffle menu to go to your flows and create the flow there.

Depending on what you want the Flow to do, you will need the respective permissions, of course.

**Edit**: Your screenshot shows the command tools of Classic experience. You will only see the Flow command in the Modern experience. It looks like this:

[image]

Also, the Flow command will only be visible if you have at least Edit permissions to the library.

But you can go to your Flows page via the Office App launcher at the top left. It looks like this:

[image]

If you don't see Flow in the App Launcher, even if you click **All Apps**, your license does not include it. You may want to talk to your IT department if you need a license that includes Flow.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly to go to  my flows and create from there. I still dont know why those functions are greyed out ?

Comment: I've added some details to my answer.

Comment: .I don't see Flow there. Could it be it has to do something with what offer the company got when  getting Office 365 ? that would be bad and limit me to all the advantages using flow.

Comment: There are many different Office 365 plans and not all of them include Flow. If you don't see Flow in the App Launcher, your license does not include it. You may want to talk to your IT department if you need a license that includes Flow.

Comment: I find it a bit weird because I now created a new document library but this one with the modern expereince and now Flow is available. It seems like Flow is not avaiable only for the classic document library expereince. Any advice ?

Comment: Correct. Flow is not available for the classic document library UI, but you can still access documents in such a library using Flow. If you want to create and launch Flows, you must use the modern experience.